# Unable to set timeout in Ansible shell module

Tags: ansible

I tried to set timout in Ansible shell module however it is not working. If i execute same in terminal it is working. Below is my code

```
- name: Timeout
  shell: "timeout 30s {{ execute_path_nityo }}/execute.sh"
```

Comment: If what you want is to pause the `playbook` execution and then run your script I would suggest using two tasks: one running the [`pause` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) and the other executing the script using the `shell` command.

Comment: hi the issue is, sometimes when execute.sh is executed, it hangs. so i was planning if it hangs more than 30s, it should exit and fail. i did saw we have something ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT, but not sure how it can be use in role level

Comment: the command works fine if i execute manually in linux server. if use ansible it not working. was wondering why there are such behaviour

Comment: as i observe, the task not being executed. I mean execute.sh is not working. if i removed the timeout 30s it is working fine. but if i put the timeout 30s, execute.sh not executing but timeout 30s is being execute and it waiting for 30s

Comment: the task as you listed above is probably failing because of the exit code when the timeout expires.

$ timeout 20s top
$ echo $?
124

you could add an
ignore_errors: true

or somthing like failed when rc != 124
to workaround the fact that rc will not be 0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  - name: Simulate long running op (15 sec),wait for up to 30 sec,poll every 5sec
    shell: "{{ execute_path_nityo }}/execute.sh"
    async: 30
    poll: 5
```

If you want to set a longer timeout limit for a certain task in your playbook, use async with poll set to a positive value. Ansible will still block the next task in your playbook, waiting until the async task either completes, fails or times out. However, the task will only time out if it exceeds the timeout limit you set with the async parameter.

```
    - name: Execute the script
      shell: "/tmp/script.sh 60" # Run for 60 seconds 
      async: 120 # Maximum allowed time in Seconds
      poll: 10 # Polling Interval in Seconds
```

Comment: what the impact of setting poll 5 and async 30. Will it retry 5 time the same command for 30 second?. I not quite clear from the documentation at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20run,longer%20than%20its%20async%20value).

Comment: async is the max allowed time for the task and poll will check if the task is completed or not for every x secs you define.

Comment: so to double confirm ya, poll will just check the status. it will not execute again right. It not same as retry and until in Ansible. is my understanding correct? Besides thati , i saw some pages, stated if we declared asynch and poll > positive no, other task will not be executed . It will wait for this task to be executed first. Is this true?

Comment: yes you are right. it will just check status of the job when you mention async it will run the task in background and poll will check for every x secs if job is completed or not.  After completing current task it moves to next task and it may throw error if some issues and if time limit is reached. you can even test with a sample script.

Comment: Did it worked as expected. Let me know if any issues.

Comment: Ii have implemented it. but unable to test. as the script is like shutdown server script. so it rarely occurs. i implmented this if incasse there is issue in shutting down the server, a timeout should be hit. this hardly able to test. but i tested with sleep was working fine